# CSS only scroll middle container while there are still items in it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a web page to show a list of doctors. I should call fetch to get an array of doctors with js, and then put them on my page. for instance, see this website (it is in the Persian language, but as you can guess, the middle container are doctors and there's one class for each doctor). I have two problems with styling the page when the object array is ready:
1st: How can I mimic this? I mean, while there are still doctors on the list, I want that the middle container is scrolled and left and the top container to stay right there. But when doctors are finished (at the end of the list), the user is able to scroll and see the rest of the page.
[The site I want to mimic](https://www.darmankade.com/gastroenterology-and-hepatology-specialist/)
[image: The middle container must be scrolled until it is finished]

[image: Schematic of my webpage]

As you can see in my webpage schematic, I want to implement the doctors div in a way that until there are more doctor classes to be seen, the doctors div will scroll. Only when the scrolling down is finished the user is able to scroll down to the next section, or vice versa, when he wants to scroll up, he should be able to do so when he has scrolled up to the top to see the previous section.

My second issue is a minor one. I'm not sure How to set the height of the doctors div because there could be an unknown number of doctors classes (each for one doctor) so the solution must also handle the unknown number of items to be placed in the doctors div (only after I fetched the doctors using the API would I be able to know the number of items to put in the doctors div)
Thanks.

Comment: in your provided example the side column has a sticky position with a `top:0;` which stops it from scrolling while the rest of the page is scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the website you shared. You can do something like this.

Link: https://codepen.io/en0ndev/pen/RwGOgMX

```css
header {
  text-align:center;
  padding:5pt;
  background:black;
  color:#fff;
}
footer {
  text-align:center;
  padding:5pt;
  background:black;
  color:#fff;
}
.main-div {
  display:flex;
}
.left-div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width:50%;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  max-height:200px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.right-div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width:50%;
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  height:200px;
}
.doctor {
  display:block;
  color:white;
  padding:5pt;
}
.menu {
  display:block;
  color:white;
  padding:5pt;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="left-div">
      <div class="doctor">Doctor1</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor2</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor3</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor4</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor5</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor6</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor7</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor8</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor9</div>
      <div class="doctor">Doctor10</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
      <div class="menu">Menu1</div>
      <div class="menu">Menu2</div>
      <div class="menu">Menu3</div>
      <div class="menu">Menu4</div>
      <div class="menu">Menu5</div>
      <div class="menu">Menu6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a perfect clean code but it'll give you the idea of how to do it. in your provided example the side column has a sticky position with a `top:0;` which stops it from scrolling while the rest of the page is scrollable. so i tried to make something like that as a simple how to.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 70rem;
  width: 20rem;
}

.top {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
}

.doctors {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30rem;
}

.right-col {
  float: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 20%;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <nav class="top"></nav>
    <section class="doctors"></section>
    <aside class="right-col"></aside>
  </div>
</main>
```